# PHP access nth row from result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that returns 5 rows.

```
SELECT name, email, address from users
```

How would I assign say, 3 row from this result set to a row?

Something like, `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result[3])`?

Comment: Please note - `mysql_*` is being deprecated, and should not be used for new code. See for example http://www.webmaster-source.com/2011/07/25/php-to-deprecate-mysql-extension-in-favor-of-mysqli-and-pdo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested you can use LIMIT to do this directly in the database but if you would like to to this programatically with PHP you can use `mysql_data_seek` - Please note that the mysql_ methods are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP.

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 2); // rows start at 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this::
USE `LIMIT`

Here the value before the comma implies the n'th row, and the value after the comma implies the number of rows to be fetched.

```
SELECT name, email, address from users LIMIT 3,1
```

Comment: What if he wants to get all the rows, but use row 3? That can't be done without loading into some sort of object list/array.

Comment: Thanks all. Yeah, I was looking for a solution and did see that this is better done by a mysql limit; but I am returning the recordset anyway. So, wanted to see if there was a way to avoid running query eachtime. Looks like TML's response answers my question. But I do realize that mysql_ methods are depreciated.

Comment: I have just suggested an option..:-)